# creating sms bubbles with alternate positions

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to add a TextView each time a button is pressed. But the thing is i want it to be added as in sms app.
The first time I click thebutton the TextView will be at the left of the screen. The next time the button is clicked the newly created TextView should be at the right side.

I tried with the following code, but it didn't work.

```
public void sendMessage(View view){

    EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message=editText.getText().toString();


    LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout01);


    TextView text=new TextView(this);
    text.setText(message);
    text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    if(flag){
        text.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);          
    }
    else
        text.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    flag=!flag;
    layout.addView(text);
}
```

'flag' is of boolean type which is declared at the beginning of the class.

EDIT -

Is it possible that i create two more layouts(one for displaying TextView on left and the other to display on right). But I don't know how to use different layouts in the same screen.

Thanks for your help

Comment: try putting a'{}' after flag=!flag

Answer (score 0):

```
public void sendMessage(View view){

    EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message=editText.getText().toString();


    LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout01);


    TextView text=new TextView(this);
    text.setText(message);
    text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    if(flag){
        text.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        flag=!flag;          
    }
    else
      {
        text.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    flag=!flag;
      }
    layout.addView(text);
}
```

Comment: try switching the statements inside 'if' and 'else' and if the layout is always in the right then the problem is the flag setting back to true each time you click the button